# Counting number of people in intersection of two sets, given size of each

Tags: combinatorics

I have been given the following problem:

> $70$ people attend an international conference. $40$ people speak Spanish and $45$ people speak English. How many people they speak both languages?

To solve it, I tried the following:
$$40 + 45 = 85$$
$$85-70=15$$
Is this correct, and why does it work?

Comment: $$P(A+B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(AB)$$

Comment: @SubhadeepDey It´s probably good that you cannot downvote. In my opinion there is no serious reason to downvote the question, although it has no integral or is about group theory.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be a set and $|A|$ be the number of elements in $A$. We have the following formula: 
$$
|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A \cap B|
$$
From your question, assuming that everyone attending the conference speaks either English or Spanish or both, if we let $A=${people who speak Spanish} and $B=${people who speak English}, then we have
$$
|A|=40 \\
|B|=45 \\
|A\cup B|=70
$$
Substitute those into the equation to find $|A\cap B|=15$, so you are correct.

Comment: By the way, this question is not directly related to probability. It's a counting problem.

Comment: Why is everybody attending speaking either Spanish or English or both? Yes, this is a counting problem, and one with some missing hypothesis...

Comment: @Did I am not sure what do you mean by your comment. Yes, strictly speaking the question didn't state all the hypothesizes clearly but from the context I assumed that it is some high school exercise. Anyway, what's the point of leaving the comment now? The question was posted very long time ago and the chances are that the OP got what he wanted. I don't understand what is gained by leaving me this comment now.

Comment: Accuracy of answers posted on the site, perhaps? Naive me was imagining that, *even after six months*, some correction could be appended to an answer, to explain correctly the underlying mathematics.

Comment: @Did I totally agree with your point but I think our opinion differ on some minor details. To me, the left-out hypothesis of this question (i.e. every people must speak either Spanish or English) was just overlooked by the OP. I assumed from the context that it was the case and answered the question accordingly. Your point is valid though but if I edit my answer to add the assumption it'd unnecessary bump the question to the front page, which I think is an overkill.

Comment: Leaving as is an answer assuming implicitely a crucial hypothesis not mentioned by the OP (and not obvious at all, if you ask me) strikes me as far worse that bumping once an answer from six months ago to the front page to make it mathematically correct.

Comment: It's the difference in our background, then. In my experience, the question fits perfectly in the category "high school exercises on counting problem", checking the OP's profile reinforce my believe. I thought the left out detail was trivial and answered the question with that implicit assumption, it didn't cross my mind that the assumption is by no mean obvious. I respect your point of view and acknowledged that there might be a lot of people who are of the same view as you. I'll edit add the assumption.

Comment: New version unambiguous.